# Parsing curl links and point to own server

Tags: php, curl, cross-domain

I'm trying to set up a very basic proxy script to pull external contents and execute some scripts on them. To bypass the same origin policy, I'm using curl to fetch the contents

```
    <?php

    $url = 'http://www.mozilla.org';

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/1.0");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result= curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;

    ?>
```

However this doesn't fetch all the CSS + images etc. I inserted a 'base' reference but it only points to the original source

```
    echo '<base href="http://www.mozilla.org"/>';
```

My question is, what methods should I use to parse all of the CSS, img, and other js links so that on each page of the pulled external content, the URL should always be something like:

```
   http://mydomain.com/curl.php?url=http://www.mozilla.org/Main-page.html/
   http://mydomain.com/curl.php?url=http://www.mozilla.org/Main-page.html/Sub-page.html
```

Thanks

Comment: Since you know the sites name `www.mozilla.org` do a `str_replace()` with yours

Comment: you may also want to include `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);` so the site knows the users browser and can server content accoringly

Comment: This is really difficult. An external file (image/css/script) may have an absolute or a relative path, a path may be generated using javascript (at client-side), and so on. I already tried, but falled down.

Comment: You mean replace all of mozilla's href links with something like `http://mydomain.com/curl.php?url=http://www.mozilla.org` ?

Comment: `$result=str_replace('mozilla.org', 'fakezilla.com', $result);`

Comment: Basically what I want to do is, each time the target page is loaded by the user, all of the CSS, imgs, js and other files, regardless of absolute or relative paths, will have their href replaced with `http://mydomain.com/curl.php?url=http://www.mozilla.org` and fetched this way. Thus bypassing the same origin restriction

Comment: Nah, OP means he want to create a web proxy that handle each external things required by the page.

Comment: yea @Ninsuo that's what I want. Have you tried this before? What methods did you use

Comment: I tried glype and it's quite slow and sometimes failed to load certain js files. Phproxy never worked for me and I don't know perl so I can't use CGIproxy. Don't know any other ones

Comment: you will also need to setup a mod_rewrite in .htaccess to /index.php?url=... then use `if(isset($_GET['url']) $url=$_GET['url'];` so your script gets the remote file too

Comment: As I already said (3rd comment), this is really difficult. You need to interpret Javascript at server-side and then replace all absolute/relative paths using regexes. But that's very tricky.

Comment: Actually, all of the js, images and other CSS references can still point to the original source. I only want to replace all of the HREF's to point to `http://mydomain.com/curl.php?url=http://www.mozilla.org` I'm assuming that what I need to do is after pulling the content via curl, store it in a variable and then via DOM replace all the href's before re-building the page and serving it to the user.

Comment: @Ninsuo not with mod_rewrite rule as above, the local paths will be processed in .htaccess will create url with path, which index.php will retrieve with curl

Comment: The href's on the page are all relative paths, so I only need to append my URL to the back of the relative paths and then rebuild the page

Comment: You guys think my idea might work?